# Google map not display, Only logo display

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have made a div which shows a google map.The problem is it is not displaying the map but shows its logo their. Where am i doing wrong? Any suggestions please. Here is my code. This code is in `<head>` tag.

**Code**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.9976096,-87.6925979);

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center:myCenter,
            zoom:16,
            scrollwheel:false,
            draggable:false,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myCenter,
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Does your map div have a size?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. [The posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/7nqrqz9u/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add height and width to your div.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width: 520px; height: 520px;"  ></div>
```